# İs there any way different way than GND's Arduino

Tags: input, arduino-uno, electronics

İ'm making  a project on my arduino uno when i figured out i had no more GND left to finish the circuit. İs there any other way to optimize, use pins as input maybe. İ tried whit other websites, however, they weren't much of a use. Can you show an example also. 
Thank you sooo much in advance, 
Dario

Comment: Can't you just connect multiple GND wires to one GND on the board?

Comment: No, two wires don't fit into one slot

Comment: connect them outside...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dario,

There are only 3 ground pins on the Arduino Uno, but don't be afraid to "breakout" these pins with wire. It doesn't matter if you connect multiple component grounds together, as long as they are connected to ground with no resistance between them, the circuit will close.

Strip board and pin headers will help you here, try this: http://www.instructables.com/id/Home-Made-Arduino-Prototype-Shield/